# If and REGEXTRACT

Tags: regex, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a text *(see below)* where
I would like to extract the date only for the specific status, when the date appears after "New on Date".

I want the formula to answer: if the status is "New" then extract the "date".

I tried this: `=If(A2 = "New",REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d{1,}?\/\d{1,}?\/\d{4})"),)`
I also tried the same by adding Find and Search but still unsuccessful. 
I know that this part of the formula works: `REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d{1,}?\/\d{1,}?\/\d{4})")`

But I do not manage to find the other part: Would anyone have a guess?

> Contract Rejected/Contract Withdrew on Date: 11/11/2016 6:23:33 AM and Modified by: Eletttt|| Offer Negotiation on Date: 6/2/2016 5:36:04 AM and Modified by: Dexx|| HR Screening on Date: 4/14/2016 2:30:57 AM and Modified by: Dexxx|| New on Date: 4/14/2016 2:24:58 AM and Modified by: Dexxx|| Contract sent on Date: 6/7/2016 11:03:58 AM and Modified by: Chrisyyy|| Pending Contract Approval on Date: 6/7/2016 4:56:55 AM and Modified by: Debxxx|| HM Interview on Date: 5/10/2016 12:40:30 AM and Modified by: Debxxx

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean you only need the date after `New on Date:`? Try `REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "New on Date:\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})")`

Comment: You got it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to extract the date after `New on Date`, you need to add this text to the pattern and keep the capturing group where it is now:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "New on Date:\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})")
```

See the screenshot (with the data inside B29 cell):

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pIXCFi/1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler one for you:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"New on Date:\s(\d\S+)")
```

[image]